# Change overview map postion in map from right to left

Tags: openlayers-2

I am using OpenLayers 2.12. I have added an OpenLayers OverviewMap control. This overview map tool is located on the right side of the map panel by default. I would like it to be positioned on the left side instead (see image).

[image: Image showing overview map control on the left side of the map]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overview map layout is controlled by the theme style, you can change the default styles in `openlayers/theme/default/style.css`.

Find following two style items:

```
.olControlOverviewMapContainer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.olControlOverviewMapMinimizeButton,
.olControlOverviewMapMaximizeButton {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Change the `right: 0` to `left: 0`, that is:

```
.olControlOverviewMapContainer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.olControlOverviewMapMinimizeButton,
.olControlOverviewMapMaximizeButton {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**EDIT:**

For the overview map maximize button symbol, it is hard coded inside openlayers js library which use the image 'img/layer-switcher-maximize.png'. However, simply modifying this image (rotate 180 deg) is not a good idea because the layer switcher is also using the same image. I would suggest to create a new image (just rotate layer-siwtcher-maximize.png 180 deg to get the new image, or maybe you can create a new one) and rename it to 'overview-map-maximize.png', then change the code in `openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Control/OverviewMap.js`. Change the following line:

```
 var img = OpenLayers.Util.getImageLocation('layer-switcher-maximize.png');
```

to:

```
 var img = OpenLayers.Util.getImageLocation('overview-map-maximize.png');
```

The minimize button image is of no problem since it's symmetric.

Comment: Thanks. but this symbol does not change. I me curve side on left and plain on right.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing it's position with CSS (as described by Mingfeng), you need to redraw icon, since default icon doesn't look suitable for left side (and there is no suitable icon bundled with OpenLayers). So, open up your image editor and modify img/layer-switcher-maximize.png.

Name for that image is hardcoded into OpenLayers, so you can't create your own image with different name.

Also you notice, that expanded overview map overlaps with '-' icon. To avoid that, modify CSS for .olControlOverviewMapElement and change padding to:

```
padding: 10px 10px 10px 18px
```